# How can I increase UrlFetchApp quota to frexible without the Early Access Program?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, urlfetch

I need to increase `UrlFetchApp` calls to over 100,000/day which means I want to change it to "flexible" plan. (Now I am using GSuite business/enterprise/education plan).

I know I need to join Early Access Program but they are not currently accepting new applications to it.

Is there any way I can increase `UrlFetchApp` calls without joining Early Access Program?

Comment: Well, if you want to do more than 100K requests via `UrlfetchApp` in a day, you are better off with cloud functions and good old Node.js (or whatever lang you prefer to write your backend in that is supported). Maybe there is a way to optimize it? If so, you can post the question on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for peers to check.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to increase your Apps Script quota and as you said Google is not accepting applicant for Early Access.

As @OlegValter has suggested if you need to reach much higher requests that the quota offers you should think about creating a proper backend structure for your case. There are option like Google Cloud functions that would help you go serverless.

Also if you try to explain what you are trying to do along with some code there may be a good chance that there are ways to optimize your code and stay inside the quota.