# Is it possible to increase the limit for URL Fetch daily quota for the Apps Script API?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

We have hundreds of users and we occasionally get blocked because we exceed the quota for UrlFetch. Is it possible to increase this limit? Or is there another workaround so we don't get throttled?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I increase UrlFetchApp quota to frexible without the Early Access Program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62024847/how-can-i-increase-urlfetchapp-quota-to-frexible-without-the-early-access-progra)

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, it is possible, you would need to associate your script with a standard project from GCP (in case you have not done this yet). What I mean by this is that you need to create a separate project on GCP, then enable the APIs and configure the scopes and everything manually, and then associate it with your script from the script settings (see screenshot).

[image]

After all that just go to the project, then IAM & Admin >> Quotas and click "Edit quotas". This is also officially documented [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6301355) and make sure that billing is enabled for the project.

What you would be doing with all this is submitting a request for the Google team in charge to review it and decide if approve it or not. It can take a couple of days for you to get a response from them.

I can't guarantee that the quota that you need to increase would be available, but at least this is how you can request any quota increase for any script you may have.

If you already have a project from GCP with the Apps Script API enabled, you can just follow the instructions to submit the request without having to follow the other steps.

Comment: Instead of adding a clarification prepending it with "Edit:" fix your post. There is a timestamp showing if the post was edited and it links to the post version history.

Comment: I don't see this option available? Is there someone we can contact for technical support. We have a Google Sheets add-in serving thousands of users

Comment: I tried this, but I don't see the quota option that links to the UrlFetchApp limit